# How to use MonoGame's Curve class

Tags: c#, monogame

I am developing a game using the MonoGame Library and I want to use the Curve class for the jump force, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it. I've looked at the [docs](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Curve.html) and also on [github](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Curve.cs).

The CurveKeyCollection in the Curve class is private and the constructor doesn't accept any arguments, so how do you actually add/remove/edit the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the instance property `Keys` to access the `CurveKeyCollection`.

```
// Position on the curve.
float position;

//Value of the control point.
float value;

//Tangent approaching point from the previous point on the curve.
float tangentIn;

//Tangent leaving point toward next point on the curve.
float tangentOut;

// CurveContinuity enum:
// CurveContinuity.Smooth
// CurveContinuity.Step

Curve curve = new();
curve.Keys.Add(new CurveKey(position, value, tangentIn, tangentOut, CurveContinuity.Smooth));
```